# Restore SQL Server 2008 R2 Express from Description

Tags: sql-server-2008

When backing up SQL Server we have the opportunity to input a description of the backup.  Yet non of the Microsoft tools will show that description for restoring.  Is there a way for me to review the description of the backup to select that one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve backup information from the backup file itself.

[RESTORE HEADERONLY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178536(v=sql.105).aspx) includes the description in the result set (if that's what you meant; it isn't clear if you want to get the description from a backup file or from system tables)

---

Another solution is to query the `msdb` for relevant information:

```
SELECT database_name, description, ... FROM msdb.dbo.backupset;
```